# Issue with a Second Exchange Account

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I'm trying to set up a student user with two different exchange accounts.  She can work on the one that she's logged on as for the AD, but not the second one.  When she tries to log in as the second one, it keeps asking for a password, but never accepts it.  So when they just hit cancel and the Outlook profiles loads when she clicks on the second account it says: "The set of folders cannot be opened. You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronize your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost)."

Any idea what's going on?  It's on Small business server 2011, with Exchange 2010.

Comment: Does it work if you disable the offline file use?

Comment: @GregAskew No it doesn't.

Comment: It displays this error when OST use is disabled? `You must connect to Exchange as the current profile to access the .OST`

Comment: @GregAskew It says: "The set of folders cannot be opened.  You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronize your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost)."

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be denying access because you didn't authenticate. Have you tried using domain\username while typing in the password? You may have to hit change user if it autofills the username. You should also try username@domain or even the email address itself and try again.

Comment: I am trying student@email.ca (of course that isn't the email).  It works when I'm logged in as the student AD account, but if I log in as anybody else, it doesn't work.

Comment: So this user has two exchange mailboxes, but does he/she have to AD accounts? Are you saying the student@email.ca is the AD account that she wants to use and the other one you haven't listed is working? I'm assuming each mailbox is tied directly to AD so you should specify the credentials of the AD account you're trying to access. It may also be an issue with the autodiscover service. It will automatically try to access the current AD account you're on. Try specifying the SMTP settings manually instead of letting it auto-detect.

Comment: I mean the prefix of the emails are the same logins for AD.  So, if it's logged in as student, only student@testemail.ca works; however, if I'm logged in as teacher, only teacher@testemail.ca works.

Answer (score 0):

Does the student have permissions to the second account? I find that trying to authenticate is problematic at best. Grant the primary AD account (ie what the user has logged in to) Full Mailbox and Send As Permissions.

The other method that might work - if you are using Outlook 2010 or higher is to add the second account as an additional Account - rather than an additional mailbox. That should generate a successful authentication prompt. However if the user has the password you may as well grant permissions at the server.